# storing multiple objects using HTML5 indexDB

Tags: angularjs, html

I have JSON object in the below format,

```
$scope.indexData = {
  "custid": "1",
  "addresses": [
    {
      "addressType": "P",
      "address1": ""
    },
    {
      "addressType": "M"
    }
  ],
  "personalDetails": {
    "title": "",
    "name": ""       
  }
}
```

I want to store the object using HTML5 indexDB. how do i store the object?

I tried in the following way, but no luck.

```
var db;
var request = window.indexedDB.open("newDatabase", 1);
request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
 var db = event.target.result;
        var objectStore = db.createObjectStore("customers");
        for (var i in $scope.indexData) {
                objectStore.add($scope.indexData[i]);      
        }

}
```

I am getting the following error saying: `Uncaught DataError: Failed to execute 'add' on 'IDBObjectStore': The object store uses out-of-line keys and has no key generator and the key parameter was not provided.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are specifying a keypath which instruct the store to use in-line keys. your code maybe like this:

```
var db;
var request = window.indexedDB.open("newDatabase", 1);
request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
 var db = event.target.result;
        var objectStore = db.createObjectStore("customers",{keyPath: "isbn"});
        for (var i in $scope.indexData) {
                objectStore.add({i:$scope.indexData[i], isbn:i});      
        }

}
```